# import or intercept SMS from a specific phone number , Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sms

I want to import or intercept the SMS messages from a specific phone-number in my application. Is such a thing possible on an iphone ,  even a jailbreaked one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The telephony stack mainly consists of one application binary called **CommCenter**.

CommCenter communicates directly with the modem using a number of serial lines of which two are used for AT commands related to SMS transfers. It handles incoming SMS messages by itself without invoking any other process, besides when the device notiﬁes the user about a newly arrived message after storing it in the SMS database.
The user SMS application is only used for reading SMS messages stored in the database
and for composing new messages and does not itself directly communicate with the modem.

SMS messages are handled by the CommCenter process.

The interface for
CommCenter consists of sixteen virtual serial lines,
`/dev/dlci.h5-baseband.[0-15]` and
`/dev/dlci.spi-baseband.[0-15]` on the 2G and the 3G iPhone, respectively.

Without root access, probably you can't get these informations.

Ref: http://www.usenix.org/

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't be possible with any public APIs.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible on jailbroken iPhones. You can see biteSMS is doing well in this manner.You need to be have on root. Means you need to install your app as root app and you need a jailbroken device. Then you can get access to SMS database from phone and then you can do sqlite operations on it. Search on google and stackoverflow you will get the path of the sms database.